# How to guarantee a C++ type's number of bits

Tags: c++, types, cross-platform, typedef

I am looking to `typedef` my own arithmetic types (e.g. Byte8, Int16, Int32, Float754, etc) with the intention of ensuring they comprise a specific number of bits (and in the case of the float, adhere to the IEEE754 format). How can I do this in a completely cross-platform way?

I have seen snippets of the C/C++ standards here and there and there is a lot of:

"**type** is *at least* **x** bytes"

and not very much of:

"**type** is *exactly* **x** bytes".

Given that `typedef Int16 unsigned short int` may not necessarily result in a 16-bit Int16, is there a cross-platform way to guarantee my types will have specific sizes?

Comment: It is possible to use templates to at compile verify that the chosen type is the correct sizeof() and if not try going down the line until you find one that does match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use exact-width integer types `int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t` declared in `<cstdint>`. This way the sizes are fixed on all the platforms

Comment: ...all platforms that provide them. If the platform doesn't *have* (for example) a 16-bit type, then it simply won't have `int16_t`.

Comment: It's easy enough to get around "don't have exactly the size I want" by using the "at least X bits" types ( http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h#Minimum-width_integer_types ).  Of course, the original question ruled out "**type** is at _least_ **x** bytes" .

Answer (score 6):

The only available way to truly guarantee an exact number of bits is to use a bit-field:

```
struct X { 
    int abc : 14; // exactly 14 bits, regardless of platform
};
```

There is some upper limit on the size you can specify this way -- at least 16 bits for `int`, and 32 bits for `long` (but a modern platform may easily allow up to 64 bits for either). Note, however, that while this guarantees that arithmetic on `X::abc` will use (or at least emulate) exactly 14 bits, it does *not* guarantee that the size of a `struct X` is the minimum number of bytes necessary to provide 14 bits (e.g., given 8-bit bytes, its size could easily be 4 or 8 instead of the 2 that are absolutely necessary).

The C and C++ standards both now include a specification for fixed-size types (e.g., `int8_t`, `int16_t`), but no guarantee that they'll be present. They're required if the platform provides the right type, but otherwise won't be present. If memory serves, these are also required to use a 2's complement representation, so a platform with a 16-bit 1's complement integer type (for example) still won't define `int16_t`.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the types declared in [stdint.h](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdint.h). This is part of the [standard library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), so it is expected (though technically not guaranteed) to be available everywhere. Among the types declared here are `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint16_t`, `int32_t`, `uint32_t`, `int64_t`, and `uint64_t`. Local implementations will map these types to the appropriate-width type for the given complier and architecture.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible.

There are platforms where `char` is 16 or even 32 bits.

Note that I'm not saying there are **in theory** platforms where this happens... it is a real and quite concrete possibility (e.g. DSPs).

On that kind of hardware there is just no way to use 8 bit only for an operation and for example if you need 8 bit modular arithmetic then the only way is doing a masking operation yourself.

The C language doesn't provide this kind of emulation for you...

With C++ you could try to build a class that behaves like the expected <strike>native</strike> elementary type in most cases (with the exclusion of `sizeof`, obviously). The result will have however truly horrible performances.

I can think to no use case in which forcing the hardware this way against its nature would be a good idea.

Comment: It is however possible at compile time to verify that the type is a certain size, so for some platforms you simply won't get your program to compile.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use C++ templates at compile time to check and create new types on the fly that do fit your requirements, specifically that `sizeof()` of the type is the correct size that you want.

Take a look at this code: [Compile time "if"](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Templates/Template_Meta-Programming#Example%3a_Compile-time_.22If.22).

Do note that if the requested type is not available then it is entirely possible that your program will simply not compile. It simply depends on whether or not that works for you or not!